# Glassfish config http methods

Tags: apache, http, web-applications, glassfish

I'm trying disable some http methods on my glassfish.

I would like know how I can does not provide a communication through "option" and "trace" http methods on glassfish v3.

```
< Allow: TRACE, OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following security constraint to your web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Forbidden</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>          
          <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
          <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
     </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: i tried this, but doesn't works... i'm using 3.1 version... some parameter need be able?